# When can I use "where" to introduce an attributive clause?

Tags: grammar, clauses

```
I wonder in which case I can use the word "where" to introduce an attributive clause.
```

For example, when a sentence contains the word "situation":
It's really a difficult situation in which you can do nothing.

We can say:
It's really a difficult situation where you can do nothing.

When can I use "where" or what words can be followed by an attributive clause that is introduced  by "where"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As either an interrogative or a relative, *where* can be thought of as a ‘pro-locative’—that is, just as a pro-noun stands for a noun phrase, *where* stands for a phrase (usually a preposition phrase) expressing location. It most comfortably takes (literal or figurative) spatial locations, either static or the goals of movement, as its referents—the sort of locations employed with prepositions like *at*, *in*, *to*.

> The library where I did my research ← *The library **at which*** . . .
>   The situation where we find ourselves ← *The situation **in which*** . . .
>   The country where he is going ← *The country **to which*** . . .

In formal writing, and to a somewhat lesser extent in casual speech,*where* may be uncomfortable with locatives expressing the origins of literal or figurative movement. For instance, you can get away with this in casual speech:

> The University of Wisconsin, where I graduated from . . .

But in academic copy you would do better to write

> The University of Wisconsin, **which** I graduated from . . .  *OR*
>   The University of Wisconsin, **from which** I graduated  . . .

And *where* is generally uncomfortable with locations and goals which are not felt to be in some sense ‘spatialized’; these require *which* + preposition (either pied-piped or stranded) instead.

> <sup>ok</sup> The principle **on which** he rests his argument . . .  *but not*
>   <sup>∗</sup> The principle **where** he rests his argument . . .
>   <sup>ok</sup> The goal **which** I am striving toward . . .  *but not*
>   <sup>∗</sup> The goal where I am striving . . .

I know of no reliable *a priori* method of distinguishing what referents will be acceptable with where from what will not.

Comment: The prepositions are governed by the various verbs; that's why they vary so much. _Where_ can be substituted for all of them, which is a simplification because transitivizing prepositions serve to allow a direct object; but when the object's moved to the front of the verb, pied-piping the meaningless prepositions seems like more work than it's worth. You don't even need to know them until you've heard the verb. And indeed _where_ is much more common than pied-piped prepositions, outside of stuffy boilerplate.

Comment: @JohnLawler Sometimes even knowing the verb doesn't help: **The principle where he rests his argument* doesn't work, but *The pillow where he rests his head* does.

Comment: Not all verbs used metaphorically carry along the affordances of their normal uses.